# Can't show icon with fontawesome's react-js library

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

```
import "./App.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

function App() {
return (
<div className="container">
  <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Ara..." id="search_input"> 
</input>
  <button type="button" className="btn btn-light" id="search_button"><FontAwesomeIcon 
icon="search" /></button>

  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" id="buttons">E-Twinning</button>
  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" id="buttons">Erasmus</button>
</div>
 );
 }

export default App;
```

I need to help about this. I have a png and svg file in background I tried show to svg and png files but it didn't work. I tried both method like as above and both working wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use string in the `icon` prop ( the way you are using), you need to add those icons using `library.add()` to make it work.

Read more [here](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react). Check section **"Using Icons via Global Use"**

One other way is to import individual icons and use them.

`import { faSearch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";`

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />`